# Using moment helper in assemble.io

Tags: momentjs, assemble

I'm having a problem with the moment js using the `assemble.io` helpers. The software we use allows us to use these helpers to customize our documents. I'm trying to add days to a date. I want our invoice to add 30 days to the invoice date as the due date. Here is what I've tried:

`InvoiceDate` is the var that the software uses to pull in the date.

```
{{moment InvoiceDate add="30, 'd'" format="MMM DD, YYYY"}}
{{moment InvoiceDate add="30, 'days'" format="MMM DD, YYYY"}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-dates.html
https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Which is the value of `InvoiceDate`? Please note that [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) accepts ISO 8601 and RFC 2822 strings.

Comment: When I just print {{InvoiceDate}} I get this 2019-01-28T00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [README.md examples](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-moment#optional-yaml-front-matter) for the moment helper, the value being passed to the `add` property needs to be an object with the key being the granularity ("days") and the value being the amount (30).

You can't format an object as a literal in Handlebars, so the data will need to be passed in somehow. If you're using software that handles frontmatter, then you can do something like this:

```
---
modifiers:
  invoiceDate:
    days: 30
---
{{moment InvoiceDate add=modifiers.invoiceDate format="MMM DD, YYYY"}}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to somehow include the modifier on your context for Handlebars to see:

```
let fn = Handlebars.compile('{{moment InvoiceDate add=modifiers.invoiceDate format="MMM DD, YYYY"}}');
let data = {
  InvoiceDate: new Date(),
  modifiers: {
    invoiceDate: {
      day: 30
    }
  }
};

console.log(fn(data));
```

Comment: I tried to add the frontmatter to the beginning of the document and it rendered a blank page. I added it after the css and it rendered the document but not the frontmatter.

Comment: You'll have to add the data however the tool that you're using is asking for it. I used the frontmatter example since I thought you might be using assemble. If you're using a different tool, then you'll have to see how to add that data to your page.